# drawing point depend on it is distance from triangle vertices

Tags: java, android, algorithm

I am using Android, and I need to draw a point using given distances from triangle vertices so for example:

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Qnu9.png)

I have three well defined points (A,B,C)
and I want to draw the P point using three given values (AP,BP,CP) using android.
thanks alot.

Comment: How do you define a point in your program? This is a problem of *trilateration* and there are well known solutions, it's just a matter of writing them in terms needed by your program https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/True_range_multilateration#Solution_methods

Comment: In general, you cannot. Three _arbitrary_ distances do not define a point. Two distances _may_ define it, and then the third distance is cast in concrete. Where your `given distances` are coming from?

Comment: you need to solve the system of equations ```(x1-x)*(x1-x)+(y1-y)*(y1-y)=d1*d1``` etc. The solution is a bit cumbersome. you take eq1, compute the difference with eq2 so that x*x and y*y cancel out, then use that equation in the first one to obtain 2 points, and then either play with eq 3 or simply check witch of the two solutions fulfill d3. Maybe check the internet for an explicit solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a pure maths question. Suppose your triangle has these points and distances to P:

```
A = (x₁, y₁)    |A - P| = d₁
B = (x₂, y₂)    |B - P| = d₂
C = (x₃, y₃)    |C - P| = d₃
```

First, take `A` and `B` and their circle equations:

```
(x - x₁)² + (y - y₁)² = d₁²
(x - x₂)² + (y - y₂)² = d₂²
```

Find the intersection of the circles:

```
(x - x₁)² + (y - y₁)² - d₁² = (x - x₂)² + (y - y₂)² - d₂² 

x² - 2xx₁ + x₁² + y² - 2yy₁ + y₁² - d₁² = x² - 2xx₂ + x₂² + y² - 2yy₂ + y₂² - d₂²
x² - 2xx₁ + x₁² + y² - 2yy₁ + y₁² - d₁² - x² + 2xx₂ - x₂² - y² + 2yy₂ - y₂² + d₂² = 0
(x² - x²) - 2xx₁ + x₁² + (y² - y²) - 2yy₁ + y₁² - d₁² + 2xx₂ - x₂² + 2yy₂ - y₂² + d₂² = 0
- 2xx₁ - 2yy₁ + 2xx₂ + 2yy₂ = d₁² - d₂² - x₁² - y₁² + x₂² + y₂²
x(-2x₁ + 2x₂) + y(-2y₁ + 2y₂) = d₁² - d₂² - x₁² - y₁² + x₂² + y₂²

y = (d₁² - d₂² - x₁² - y₁² + x₂² + y₂² - x(-2x₁ + 2x₂)) / (-2y₁ + 2y₂)
```

Replace it into any of the two original equations:

```
(x - x₁)² + (y - y₁)² = d₁²
(x - x₁)² + ((d₁² - d₂² - x₁² - y₁² + x₂² + y₂² - x(-2x₁ + 2x₂)) / (-2y₁ + 2y₂) - y₁)² = d₁²
```

After you expand it, you'll have a quadratic equation on `x`, since it is the only variable in the sentence. Find the two results `x'` and `x''` of the equation.

Do the same thing with `A` and `C` and find the two resulting points `x'''` and `x''''`.

Compare the first two resulting points with the last two.

```
if(x' == x''')   xᵣ = x'  
if(x' == x'''')  xᵣ = x'  
if(x'' == x''')  xᵣ = x'' 
if(x'' == x'''') xᵣ = x''
```

Now, let `xᵣ` be the answer. We know that `P = (xᵣ, yᵣ)`. To find `yᵣ`, just take two of the original equations and replace `x` for `xᵣ`. You will have two quadratic equations where `y` is the variable, leaving you the results `y'`, `y''` (from the first) and `y'''`, `y''''` (from the second).

```
if(y' == y''')   yᵣ = y'  
if(y' == y'''')  yᵣ = y'  
if(y'' == y''')  yᵣ = y'' 
if(y'' == y'''') yᵣ = y''
```

Finally, you have your `P = (xᵣ, yᵣ)`.